# Invalid input syntax error for type numeric: V1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am loading a csv file to create a new table with a column containing a decimal value of 1.449043781.

Here's my code

```
CREATE TABLE table (
   v1 float
);
```

Postgres spits out an error saying *invalid input syntax error for type numeric* even though the value is a float. I have tried changing the data type declaration to decimal(15,13) to no avail. What am I missing here?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Are you using the copy command to load the table?  Does your file have a header row?   Can you provide the exact message from PostgreSQL?  Are there other fields in the file before the number in each row?  This value goes into a float with insert so there is no problem there (except that you need the data-type to be "double precision" to preserve ore than 6 digits of precision).

Comment: The error message means it's trying to interpret the string `'v1'` as a number. The fact that the column name `v1` appears in the CSV itself suggests that your file has a header row, and the fact that your `COPY IN` is trying to interpret this row as data means you neglected to specify the `HEADER` option.

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce - copies without errors on 9.6:

```
t=# CREATE TABLE t (
   v1 float
);
CREATE TABLE
t=# copy t from stdin;
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> 1.449043781
>> \.
COPY 1
t=# select v1,pg_typeof(v1) from t;
     v1      |    pg_typeof
-------------+------------------
 1.449043781 | double precision
(1 row)
```

also from your error, it looks you created table with numeric, not float. [And they are not the same](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) (both would accept the `1.449043781` though)